# Unable to deciper formula field syntax

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to decipher a Crystal Reports formula field, but I'm not sure what this syntax is saying. I understand what the `ISNULL()` is for, but does the `>"."` mean?

```
if isnull({r.userid}) or not ({r.userid}>".") then {r.empID} else {r.userid}}
```

What is the `or  not ({r.userid}>".")` statement saying?  I don't follow the logic in that.

Comment: `X > "."`  would be `true` when `X` is a single character that is greater than the `.` character - i.e character code 46.  Can't say *why* this logic is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting way to do this but it is basically saying 
if userid is null or if the asci value of the first character of userid is NOT greater than 46. This will return The username if it is not null or starts with anything other than special characters.